# Create a plot using only certain row values from a column in the x axis and the full column on the y axis

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a dataset of 2 variables and over 30k observations. 
one variable is country and the other is price. I want to plot the countries on the x axis but I only want to include certain rows(countries) such as "UK" & "USA" and not all the 20 countries listed in the column.

I am using ggplot but I am not sure how I would subset the dataset to include only those countries and their prices.

```
one_plot <- subset(origin_price$product_origin == c["USA", "UK", "Australia", "China"])
```

I tried to subset using the above code which is wrong, but Im struggling to find any solutions online to this particular problem.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please read the info about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to give a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269). This will make it much easier for others to help you.

Comment: Subsetting your data would probably be the easiest way to avoid surprises.

Comment: `subset( origin_price , product_origin %in% c( "USA", "UK", "Australia", "China" ) )`

Comment: @DanSlone Thank you very much

Answer (score 3):

```
y = sample(1:1000,1000) #price
x = sample(letters, 1000, replace = T) #country names

library(ggplot2)
d = data.frame(x,y)
d = subset(d, x == "a"| x == "b")
```

Use `subset` to subset dataframe and `|` to separate the countries you want to plot.

```
u = ggplot(d, aes(x = x, y = y))
u + geom_point()  # that is it.
```

Comment: `x %in% c("a", "b")` can be nicer (and generalizes nicely to more possibilities) than `x == "a" | x == "b"`. And inside `subset` you don't need `d$` - that's what the `data` argument is for.